# Error while gem install on ubuntu 12.04 aws ec2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I got a Ubuntu 12.04 instance in AWS EC2.
I just want to gem install rails.
But it shows this error message.
Is this caused by the difference gem env between sudo gem env?
Is there any ways to solve this problem except rvm implode?
What's the risk of using rvmsudo instead?

```
Fetching: atomic-1.1.15.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions for the /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@global directory.
```

gem env:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.2.2
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2014-02-24 patchlevel 545) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@global
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@global/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /home/ubuntu/.gem/specs
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@global
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gem" => "--no-ri --no-rdoc"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p545@global/bin
     - /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p545/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /sbin
     - /bin
     - /usr/games
     - /usr/local/rvm/bin
```

sudo gem env:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.15
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /var/lib/gems/1.8
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/ruby1.8
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-linux
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /var/lib/gems/1.8
     - /home/ubuntu/.gem/ruby/1.8
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
     - "gem" => "--no-ri --no-rdoc"
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this caused by the difference gem env between sudo gem env?

Quite possibly, the `rvm` Ruby is separate and different from the system Ruby environment and depends on where what `gem` gets executed according to the path.

However, it looks like you are running an rvm Ruby gem install as a different user as the owner of `/usr/local/rvm/gems` and it's subdirectories, which is supposed to be installed as `rvmsudo`

What user are you running the rvm gem install as?

You can try this:

```
chown -R user-you-want-to-run-command-as.user-you-want-to-run-command-as /usr/local/rvm/gems
```

Or also try like you mentioned `rvmsudo`. The risk there as the some of the files may have `root` ownership which you may not want if you want to be more secure.

Note that `rvmsudo` is not the recommended way but rather use `rvm` on your local directory. If you'd like to remove it you can do this:

```
rvmsudo rvm implode
sudo rm -rf /etc/rvmrc /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh /usr/local/rvm
```

Then reinstall with just `rvm`

Answer (score 5):

rvm is made to be used without sudo or specific/sudo rights.
reinstall would be more appreciated.
clean the current rvm install

`rvmsudo rvm implode
sudo rm -rf /etc/rvmrc /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh /usr/local/rvm`

and then close all consoles/bashes/terminales and login in again with the user you want to use rvm with and install it again.