# Ruby Gem Installation Error + You don't have write permissions for the /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353 directory

Tags: ruby, rubygems

In my local machine, I am trying to install a formatter gem related to date, but while installing I am getting some strange error.

```
[admin@localhost test_folder]$ gem install formatter-0.0.1.gem
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions for the /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353
directory.
```

I am not able to install it locally. Operating system is CentOS and Ruby version is Ruby2.

Comment: `sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353`

Comment: `sudo gem install formatter -v 0.0.1`

Comment: `sudo gem sources --add http://rubygems.org`

Comment: `gem sources --remove https://rubygems.org`

Comment: First you need to add all users that will be using rvm to 'rvm' group, and logout - login again, anyone using rvm will be operating with `umask u=rwx,g=rwx,o=rx`. 
To start using RVM you need to run `source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh` in all your open shell windows, in rare cases you need to reopen all shell windows.

Answer (score 12):

chmodding isn't the best way here.
Propably ok for a local machine, but not for production.

rvm is made to be used without sudo or specific/sudo rights. reinstall would be more appreciated. clean the current rvm install 
rvm implode

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/rvmrc /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh /usr/local/rvm
```

and then close all consoles/bashes/terminales and login in again with the user you want to use rvm with and install it again.

see also here:
[Error while gem install on ubuntu 12.04 aws ec2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22368393/error-while-gem-install-on-ubuntu-12-04-aws-ec2/24891726#24891726)

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353
```

**sudo chmod -R 777 specific_folder_path**

Thanks a lot to Rajarshi Das